# How to merge multiple pipes into one or vice versa

Tags: haskell, conduit

Is it possible to merge multiple pipes into one or vice versa?

I'm struggling with implementing the following functions.

```
merge :: (Monad m) => [Pipe l i o u m r] -> Pipe [l] [i] [o] m [r]

split :: (Monad m) => Pipe [l] [i] [o] m [r] -> [Pipe l i o u m r]
```

Comment: Can you outline the behavior you need? It is possible to build fairly general merge functions for sources (concatenated or sorted) and sinks (stop when first sink is done or when all are done). Conduit merging tends to be more specialized. I don't think splitting a pipe of lists is possible without IO.

Comment: @comatose I think the type signature needs to be fixed. The `u` probably needs to be dropped.

Comment: @NathanHowell I think he wants to tak a list of pipe and combine them into one pipe so that he can feed in a list of lists. merge [mapD (*2), mapD (+2)], would (*2) the first element of a list and (+2) to the second, and either fail if the list was longer or use id I guess.

Comment: @Davorak There are many possible ways to combine pipes. Here are two different ways that I commonly use: `mergeSinks :: (Monad m, Monoid r) => [Pipe i i Void () m r] -> Pipe i i Void () m r` and `mergeSources :: (Ord o, Monoid u, Monad m) => [Pipe l i o u m ()] -> Pipe l i o u m ()`. But he may also want `mconcat :: [Pipe l i o u m ()] -> Pipe l i o u m ()`... or even `foldM`, it's hard to guess.

Comment: @Davorak I missed `[u]` between `[o]` and `m`. For the 2nd comment, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanHowell I want `merge` to take a list of pipes and return a new pipe which distributes its individual input of a list among those pipes. Say, given an input stream, e.g. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]..], and 3 target files named 'file1', 'file2' and 'file3', I want to store [1,4..] to 'file1', [2,5..] to 'file2' and [3,6..] to 'file3' using conduit.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment, it sounds like you can more easily accomplish what you're trying to do just by chaining some sinks together:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Serialize.Put (putListOf, putWord32le)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as Cb
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as Cl
import qualified Data.Conduit.Cereal as Cc

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let source = Cl.sourceList [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
      encoder = Cc.conduitPut $ putListOf putWord32le

  runResourceT . runPipe $ source >+> do
    Cl.isolate 1 >+> encoder >+> Cb.sinkFile "/tmp/1.bin"
    Cl.isolate 1 >+> encoder >+> Cb.sinkFile "/tmp/2.bin"
    Cl.isolate 1 >+> encoder >+> Cb.sinkFile "/tmp/3.bin"
    Cl.sinkNull
```

Comment: Hum, just realized you may actually need a sink router. We use two, one is sychronous: `routeToSinksBy :: (Monad m, Ord a) => (i -> a) -> Map a (Sink i m r) -> Sink i m (Map a r)`... I can get it cleaned up and published if it would be helpful. The other is asynchronous and uses sources built from `TBQueue`s to bind to each sink.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, actually, I wanted that `[1,4,7]` to 1.bin, `[2,5,8]` to 2.bin, and `[3,6,9]` to 3.bin. If there is something like "transpose", it will help. And also what if I have `cycle [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`? `routeToSinkBy` sounds pretty good. I am looking forward to that.

Comment: I have a suggestion for `conduit`, if you're involved in `conduit`. Recently, I have failed to find something like `sourceFile :: MonadResource m => Int -> FilePath -> GSource m ByteString`, which has an additional parameter for the packet size of `hGetSome`. I think it will be helpful in some cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, merging pipes has a variety of semantics.

I know that in `pipes-core` (Paolo Capriotti's fork of Gabriel Gonzalez's `pipes` library, which is another implementation of iteratees like `conduit`) there's some very general code for monoidal and multiplicative categories.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes-core/0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Pipe-Category.html#t:PipeC

For instance, using `PipeC`, a newtype that moves the type variables around to make `PipeC m r` a valid category, we can multiplex sets independent signals as `Either`s.

You also have something like `sequence` which applies across the `Monad` instance.

```
sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]
```

which will sequence various pipes "vertically" (one runs then the next) letting us write something like (using `Control.Pipe.Pipe` from Gonzalez's `pipes` package)

```
takeNPipe :: Int -> Pipe a b m [a]
takeNPipe n = sequence (replicate n await)
```

---

The type you're asking for implies both of these kinds of "merges" simultaneously. This is (I believe) impossible since you want both parallel (multiplexed) and sequential (vertical) composition at once.

Comment: I've considered using pipes before, but i didn't due to the absence of `pipes-bysestring`. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I just used it as an example. These concepts are probably general to any of the iteratee-inspired libraries. I like `pipes` a lot, though it's definitely far behind in terms of library support.